GetApps Console Xiaomi Error APP_OFFLINE_BAN_DEPLOY
We encountered the error "APP_OFFLINE_BAN_DEPLOY" while attempting to upload our application to  store. Attached is a screenshot showing the error message.All required fields are filled in

